# please explain the linux command: find /tmp -name core -type f -print | xargs /bin/rm -f

Tags: linux, find, gnome-terminal

i have been looking all throughout the google for the explanation of such commands

```
find /tmp -name core -type f -print | xargs /bin/rm -f
```

well i got the command from the net itself and explanation was also mentioned there.by now i know that this command is used to find a file named 'core' in the directory named 'tmp' and delete the file. i have used and checked this and it is perfectly working.

my problem is that i could not understand the terms used in this command like what does -type f,  and xargs do??
also how to generate such commands according to our need(obviously could not unless properly understood), and the biggest problem is what to write in google to get the help regarding this...i mean under what topic may i expect these.

please help

regards.

Comment: use man, like 'man find' on command line to see manual of find, also xargs.

Comment: you can find all the details in the manual page. To print all info, `man find` for find, `man xargs` for xargs, and `man pipe` for `|`. Google will throw you bunch of unnecessary info that will confuse you even more, ones you understand the basics, you can google you way through.

Comment: thanx for the reply 
i read it but it was not clear with some terms like "symbolic links"...whats that?

Comment: For that one, you can google...

Comment: A symbolic link is a file that just redirects to another file. So if `hi.text` is a symbolic link to `yoyo.txt`, editing `hi.text` will actually just edit `yoyo.txt`. On a more technical level, a symbolic link is a file with it's own inode that points to another inode. Hard links actually share an inode, preventing broken links. There are tons of explanations online that go into greater depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a string of unix commands:

```
 find           // name of command (in this case, "find")

 arguments to 'find':
    /tmp        // where to look
    -name core  // name to look for, "core" (optional argument)
    -type f     // files only (not, eg, directories or files contents) 
                // (optional argument)
    -print      // output the list to standard output (STDOUT)

|               // name of command (otherwise known as
                // 'pipe') this is a little program that
                // takes the output from a previous process
                // (in this case, the output from 'find')
                // and pass it to another process as input  

 xargs          // name of command ('xargs') the program
                // that will accept the output from 'print'
                // as input (directed by 'pipe'). It provides
                // a robust way to process indefinitely
                // long lists by breaking them into smaller
                // lists and passing each sublist through
                // to its command argument

 /bin/rm        // name of command for xargs to execute 
                // on its input list ('rm' = remove)
      -f        // argument to rm, only remove files, not directories.
```

That's how unix works, it's made up of lots of little single-purpose programs with obscure 2-letter names that are devoted to a single task. You string these together to achieve more complex tasks.

The correct way to find out what any one command does is to use the 'man' command with the command name in question as argument, eg

```
man find
man xargs
man rm
```

You will get pages of detailed info describing each input option and output possibilities. A name like 'xargs' is also easy to google but understandably 'find' is not (maybe try 'unix find'). Many of them have Wikipedia pages...

Perhaps you should get a decent into guide to unix ...

Comment: thanks a lot to all...it was really a great help

Comment: `|` is an operator not a command. See [link1](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) [link2](http://www.beforever.com/bashtut.htm#pipe), of course, this is true because Bash is the default shell of GNU/Linux [Link3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29). However, this might not be true with another shell or system for that matter.